# How to check for answers I haven't accepted?

Tags: discussion, support

I just came across [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55465703/) I posted that went unanswered for three years. Then when it finally got answered I must have missed the notification, because *it has now been answered for one year*. (I just finally accepted it.)

In order to prevent this kind of thing from happening, **is there a way I can get Stack Exchange sites to show me only questions I've asked that have answers but no *accepted* answers?** Then I could review them and accept those that that deserve it.